# Restrict access to old files after URL Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website developed in PHP. I have recently done the URL rewriting which works fine. However, I just found out that my pages with parameters are also accessible. For eg.

I converted this URL
domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy

After rewrite it looks like this
domainname.com/products/5/Samsung-Galaxy.html

Everything works just fine. However, My site is still accessible using the old parameters. I want if someone types in the old URL should be automatically redirected to Ideally New Page if not then index page. Google and MSN shouldn't access these pages with parameter. Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

Thanks for your input. Here is more detail to my question.

I converted this URL
domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy

After rewrite it looks like this
domainname.com/products/5/Samsung-Galaxy.html

The code looks like this.

`RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*).html$  index.php?page=product&pid=$1&proTitle=$2 [nc]`

Rewrite Works fine. However, if I try to access old URL i.e domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy the page is still accessible and on top of that being crawled by Google and other search engines. I want If someone tries to access this URL, it should direct them to Page Not Found and this should also not be sniffed by any crawlers.

Thanks a lot again for your time and I hope I can get your valuable reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need another rule which redirects the browser to the nicer looking URL if the **request** is made for the ugly looking one. For example:

```
# need to replace spaces with "-"
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)&pid=([^&\ ]+)&proTitle=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Here is a detailed explanation of what I am trying to achieve.